# Schedule a push notification

Tags: 7

I need to schedule a Push Notification, as in the [push notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications) module, every predefined set of time (e.g. every week). Looked into the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, but could not find a way to program a rule based on time.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The module **rules_scheduler** present inside [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is giving you what you need.

Details of implementation are here:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2720421
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1300068